# Google Compute Engine REST API - filter list by null value

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-compute-engine

In GCP REST API, is there a way to filter out results based on null field value? More specifically, I would want to list non-deprecated images via this API: `https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/images/list`

A list item (image) can contain following attribute (non-deprecated image is missing this attribute).

```
      "deprecated": {
        "state": "DEPRECATED",
        "replacement": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/beta/projects/debian-cloud/global/images/debian-8-jessie-v20151104"
      }
```

I have tried following `?filter` values: `deprecated=null`, `deprecated.state=null`, `deprecated.state=""`. The last one yields an empty list, former two do not work (400 bad request). I have also tried `?filter=deprecated.state="DEPRECATED"` which yields DEPRECATED images. I would neet a complement list. Is there a way to filter by `null` value?

Thanks

Comment: I know that when I get all images (unfiltered) ordered by creation date desc (first page of 100 should be sufficient) and filter out DEPRECATED images, that way I will most probably get what I need. But I would ideally want API to filter it for me.

Comment: can you please check if the non-depricated image has `deprecated.state` field or not?

Comment: @MussRahman  non-deprecated image is missing deprecated struct at all (deprecated = null)

Comment: Did you tried `--filter="(deprecated.state != "DEPRECATED" OR "OBSOLETE")"`

Answer (score 0):

I think `filter="(deprecated.state != "DEPRECATED" OR "OBSOLETE")"` will fulfil your needs

Comment: This does not work for me. I'm trying in the GCP API explorer:

GET https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{project}/global/images

project = debian-cloud
filter = (deprecated.state != "DEPRECATED" OR "OBSOLETE")

Getting:
```
    "message": "Invalid value for field 'filter': '(deprecated.state != \"DEPRECATED\" OR \"OBSOLETE\")'. Invalid list filter expression.",
}
```

Comment: Please see: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/images/list?apix_params=%7B%22project%22%3A%22debian-cloud%22%2C%22filter%22%3A%22(deprecated.state%20!%3D%20%5C%22DEPRECATED%5C%22%20OR%20%5C%22OBSOLETE%5C%22)%22%7D

Answer (score 0):

To see results where the `deprecation` field is undefined, [use the filter `-deprecated:*`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/images/list?apix_params=%7B%22project%22%3A%22debian-cloud%22%2C%22filter%22%3A%22-deprecated%3A*%22%7D&apix=true)

- From that `images.list` page, “Most Compute resources support…[AIP-160](https://google.aip.dev/160).…The `:*` comparison can be used to test whether a key has been defined.”
- From AIP-160, you can use `-` or `NOT` as negation operators.